# How to view live file system of Multipass VM using LXD driver externally?

Tags: raspberry-pi, virtual-machine, virtualization, lxd, multipass

I am using Canonical's Multipass on a Raspberry Pi with LXD driver to start virtual machines (VMs). Given my configuration, I need to view real-time changes/updates happening in the virtual machine on the host, i.e. externally from the virtual machine. The current way I can do this is by unmounting and mounting the VM image file (.img file) from time to time which is not ideal.
Is there a way of doing a real-time follow-up on the changes with the .img file?

Answer (score 2):

After reaching out to the LXD project team (thanks [Thomas Parrott](https://github.com/tomponline)
) the best way is not to mount the .img file but to use lxc. Given how Multipass is installed using the LXD driver we can access the VM with `lxc exec <instance> --project multipass -- <cmd> <args>`.